# W3 Total Cache Navigation Hover Disappeared

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently minified and tried to optimize the JS and CSS code on my site, but it took away the navigation drop down when hovering. I reverted all of the changes but cannot for the life of me get it to reappear. Whats even more odd is that its showing up in firefox but not IE or Chrome. ``

```
.left_nav
{
    border:1px solid #a6e3fc;
    padding:2%;
    background-color:#f4fcff;

}
.left_nav ul
{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.left_nav ul li
{
    padding:3% 0;
    margin:0px
}
.left_nav ul li a
{
    font-family:"latoregular";
    font-size:1em;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#45cbfe;

}
.left_nav ul li a:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#01b8fd;
}
.mid_area
{
    border:1px solid #a6e3fc;
    padding:2%;
}
       }
.sub_nav1 {
    margin:0px 0px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid #a6e3fc;
    background-color:#f4fcff;
}

.sub_nav1 ul {
    padding:4px 20px;
    margin:0px;
}

.sub_nav1 li {
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    border-right:1px solid #01b8fd;
    line-height:18px;
}

.sub_nav1 li:last-child {
    border-right:0px;
}

.sub_nav1 li a, .sub_nav li a:visited {
    font-family:"latoregular";
    font-size:14px;
    color:#01b8fd;  
    text-decoration:none;
}
.text_content1
{
    color:#0a6c91;
    padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;
    float:left;
}
.mid_area h2
{
    font-family:"latoregular";
    font-size:25px;
    color:#01b8fd;
    padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.footer_nav.col-centered.col-md-12.col-sm-8 {
  margin: 23px 0;
}

.page-list {
  list-style: outside none none;
}
.page-list li {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
```

Here is the html

```
<div class="navigation_menu "  data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="95" id="enigma_nav_top">
        <span id="header_shadow"></span>
        <div class="container navbar-container" >
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">

                      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                                <div id="menu" class="collapse navbar-collapse"><ul id="menu-top-navigation" class="nav navbar-nav"><li id="menu-item-4" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-4 active"><a title="Home" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-4273" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-4273 dropdown"><a title="Destination Travel Guides" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true">Destination Travel Guides</a><i id="parent_menu" class="fa fa-chevron-down" data-toggle="dropdown"></i>
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu multilevel">
    <li id="menu-item-3774" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-3774 dropdown-submenu"><a title="Africa" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/africa/">Africa</a>
    <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu multilevel">
        <li id="menu-item-3772" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3772"><a title="Cape Town Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/africa/cape-town/">Cape Town Travel Guide</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-3448" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-3448 dropdown-submenu"><a title="Asia" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/asia/">Asia</a>
    <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu multilevel">
        <li id="menu-item-4151" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4151"><a title="Beijing Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/asia/beijing/">Beijing Travel Guide</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3449" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3449"><a title="Hong Kong Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/asia/hong-kong/">Hong Kong Travel Guide</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3524" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3524"><a title="Tokyo Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/asia/tokyo/">Tokyo Travel Guide</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4150" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4150"><a title="Seoul Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/asia/seoul/">Seoul Travel Guide</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3450" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3450"><a title="Singapore Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/asia/singapore/">Singapore Travel Guide</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-1854" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-1854 dropdown-submenu"><a title="Europe" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/europe/">Europe</a>
    <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu multilevel">
        <li id="menu-item-2141" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2141 dropdown-submenu"><a title="Austria" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/austria/">Austria</a>
        <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu multilevel">
            <li id="menu-item-2221" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2221"><a title="Innsbruck Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/austria/innsbruck/">Innsbruck Travel Guide</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-2222" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2222"><a title="Salzburg Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/austria/salzburg/">Salzburg Travel Guide</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-2270" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2270"><a title="Vienna Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/austria/vienna/">Vienna Travel Guide</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li id="menu-item-2740" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2740 dropdown-submenu"><a title="Denmark" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/denmark/">Denmark</a>
        <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu multilevel">
            <li id="menu-item-3215" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3215"><a title="Copenhagen Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/denmark/copenhagen/">Copenhagen Travel Guide</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li id="menu-item-2308" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2308 dropdown-submenu"><a title="Germany" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/germany/">Germany</a>
        <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu multilevel">
            <li id="menu-item-3585" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3585"><a title="Berlin Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/germany/berlin/">Berlin Travel Guide</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-3523" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3523"><a title="Frankfurt Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/germany/frankfurt/">Frankfurt Travel Guide</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-2307" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2307"><a title="Munich Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/germany/munich/">Munich Travel Guide</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li id="menu-item-3586" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-3586 dropdown-submenu"><a title="Greece" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/greece/">Greece</a>
        <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu multilevel">
            <li id="menu-item-3584" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3584"><a title="Athens Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/greece/athens/">Athens Travel Guide</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-3925" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3925"><a title="Mykonos Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/greece/mykonos/">Mykonos Travel Guide</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-3945" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3945"><a title="Santorini Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/greece/santorini/">Santorini Travel Guide</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li id="menu-item-2403" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2403 dropdown-submenu"><a title="Italy" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/italy/">Italy</a>
        <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu multilevel">
            <li id="menu-item-2402" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2402"><a title="Milan Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/italy/milan/">Milan Travel Guide</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-2567" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2567"><a title="Rome Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/italy/rome-overview/">Rome Travel Guide</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-2651" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2651"><a title="Venice Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/italy/venice-overview/">Venice Travel Guide</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-2696" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2696"><a title="Florence Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/italy/florence-overview/">Florence Travel Guide</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li id="menu-item-2739" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2739 dropdown-submenu"><a title="Spain" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/spain/">Spain</a>
        <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu multilevel">
            <li id="menu-item-3288" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3288"><a title="Barcelona Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/spain/barcelona/">Barcelona Travel Guide</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-3255" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3255"><a title="Ibiza Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/spain/ibiza/">Ibiza Travel Guide</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-3619" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3619"><a title="Madrid Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/spain/madrid/">Madrid Travel Guide</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li id="menu-item-2741" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2741 dropdown-submenu"><a title="Switzerland" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/switzerland/">Switzerland</a>
        <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu multilevel">
            <li id="menu-item-3216" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3216"><a title="Bern Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/switzerland/bern/">Bern Travel Guide</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-2951" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2951"><a title="Geneva Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/switzerland/geneva/">Geneva Travel Guide</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-3078" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3078"><a title="Interlaken Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/switzerland/interlaken/">Interlaken Travel Guide</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-3108" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3108"><a title="Zurich Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/switzerland/zurich/">Zurich Travel Guide</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li id="menu-item-4013" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-4013 dropdown-submenu"><a title="Turkey" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/turkey/">Turkey</a>
        <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu multilevel">
            <li id="menu-item-4038" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4038"><a title="Cappadocia Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/turkey/cappadocia/">Cappadocia Travel Guide</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-4012" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4012"><a title="Istanbul Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/turkey/istanbul/">Istanbul Travel Guide</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li id="menu-item-4496" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-4496 dropdown-submenu"><a title="United Kingdom" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/united-kingdom/">United Kingdom</a>
        <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu multilevel">
            <li id="menu-item-4488" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4488"><a title="London Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/united-kingdom/london-overview/">London Travel Guide</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-2007" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2007 dropdown-submenu"><a title="Oceania - Australia - Pacific" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/australia-and-the-pacific/">Oceania &#8211; Australia &#8211; Pacific</a>
    <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu multilevel">
        <li id="menu-item-2745" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2745 dropdown-submenu"><a title="Australia" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/australia-and-the-pacific/australia/">Australia</a>
        <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu multilevel">
            <li id="menu-item-2829" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2829"><a title="Sydney Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/australia-and-the-pacific/australia/sydney-overview/">Sydney Travel Guide</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-2862" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2862"><a title="Melbourne Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/australia-and-the-pacific/australia/melbourne-overview/">Melbourne Travel Guide</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li id="menu-item-2749" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2749 dropdown-submenu"><a title="New Zealand" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/australia-and-the-pacific/new-zealand/">New Zealand</a>
        <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu multilevel">
            <li id="menu-item-2958" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2958"><a title="Auckland Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/australia-and-the-pacific/new-zealand/auckland-overview/">Auckland Travel Guide</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-2957" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2957"><a title="Wellington Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/australia-and-the-pacific/new-zealand/wellington/">Wellington Travel Guide</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-3773" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-3773 dropdown-submenu"><a title="United States of America" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/united-states-america/">United States of America</a>
    <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu multilevel">
        <li id="menu-item-3708" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3708"><a title="Las Vegas Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/united-states-america/las-vegas-travel-guide/">Las Vegas Travel Guide</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4220" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4220"><a title="Los Angeles Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/united-states-america/los-angeles/">Los Angeles Travel Guide</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3668" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3668"><a title="New York Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/new-york/">New York Travel Guide</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4219" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4219"><a title="San Francisco Travel Guide" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/destination-travel-guides/united-states-america/san-francisco/">San Francisco Travel Guide</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-1931" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-1931 dropdown"><a title="Cruises" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true">Cruises</a><i id="parent_menu" class="fa fa-chevron-down" data-toggle="dropdown"></i>
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu multilevel">
    <li id="menu-item-2718" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2718 dropdown-submenu"><a title="Cruise Lines" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/cruise-lines/">Cruise Lines</a>
    <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu multilevel">
        <li id="menu-item-4071" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4071"><a title="Carnival Cruises" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/cruise-lines/carnival-cruises/">Carnival Cruises</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3879" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3879"><a title="Celebrity Cruises" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/cruise-lines/celebrity-cruises/">Celebrity Cruises</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3892" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3892"><a title="Costa Cruises" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/cruise-lines/costa-cruises/">Costa Cruises</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3971" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3971"><a title="MSC Cruises" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/cruise-lines/msc-cruises/">MSC Cruises</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-2004" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2004"><a title="Norwegian Cruise Line" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/cruise-lines/norwegian-cruise-line/">Norwegian Cruise Line</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3813" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3813"><a title="Princess Cruises" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/cruise-lines/princess-cruises/">Princess Cruises</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-1930" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1930"><a title="Travel Tips and Tricks" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/travel-tips-and-tricks/">Travel Tips and Tricks</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1929" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1929 dropdown"><a title="Trip Planning Tools" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true">Trip Planning Tools</a><i id="parent_menu" class="fa fa-chevron-down" data-toggle="dropdown"></i>
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu multilevel">
    <li id="menu-item-1967" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1967"><a title="Packing Calculator" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/packing-calculator/">Packing Calculator</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1968" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1968"><a title="Budget Calculator" href="http://www.plannedtraveller.com/budget-calculator/">Budget Calculator</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>         </nav>
```

Comment: Could you please add a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/) of the problem so that we can help you troubleshoot it?

Comment: Can you post your implementation?

Comment: Posted - apologies had a bunch of edits :)

Answer (score 2):

```
.left_nav ul li
{
    padding:3% 0;
    margin:0px
}
```

Its missing a ;

```
.left_nav ul li
{
    padding:3% 0;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Also

```
.mid_area
{
    border:1px solid #a6e3fc;
    padding:2%;
}
       }
```

It has an extra }

**Last edit** full code

```
.left_nav{
    border:1px solid #a6e3fc;
    padding:2%;
    background-color:#f4fcff;
}
.left_nav ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.left_nav ul li{
    padding:3% 0;
    margin:0px;
}
.left_nav ul li a{
    font-family:"latoregular";
    font-size:1em;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#45cbfe;
}
.left_nav ul li a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#01b8fd;
}
.mid_area{
    border:1px solid #a6e3fc;
    padding:2%;
}
.sub_nav1{
    margin:0px 0px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid #a6e3fc;
    background-color:#f4fcff;
}

.sub_nav1 ul{
    padding:4px 20px;
    margin:0px;
}

.sub_nav1 li{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    border-right:1px solid #01b8fd;
    line-height:18px;
}

.sub_nav1 li:last-child {
    border-right:0px;
}

.sub_nav1 li a, .sub_nav li a:visited {
    font-family:"latoregular";
    font-size:14px;
    color:#01b8fd;  
    text-decoration:none;
}
.text_content1{
    color:#0a6c91;
    padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;
    float:left;
}
.mid_area h2{
    font-family:"latoregular";
    font-size:25px;
    color:#01b8fd;
    padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.footer_nav.col-centered.col-md-12.col-sm-8{
  margin: 23px 0;
}

.page-list {
  list-style: outside none none;
}
.page-list li {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: No dice - the site is www.plannedtraveller.com maybe I'm not providing the right info to you guys and I have something else wrong lol.

Comment: Hmm..not on the pc atm. When i get back home i will have a look at it for you it should not be that hard ita some simple thing for sure

Comment: as far as i can see it's working fine in Mozzila overall,But i noticed something strange,it's working in all other browsers for about 4-5 seconds and than it stops working

Comment: Yeah I def did - I'm wondering if I should just revert the stylesheet back? to what it was?

Comment: Try it out it might fix it